# How to efficiently chunk data.frame into smaller ones and process them

Tags: r, performance

I have a bigger data.frame which i want to cut into small ones, depending on some "`unique_keys`" ( In reffer to MySQL ). At the moment I am doing this with this loop, but it takes awfully long ~45sec for 10k rows.

```
for( i in 1:nrow(identifiers_test) ) {
  data_test_offer = data_test[(identifiers_test[i,"m_id"]==data_test[,"m_id"] &
                     identifiers_test[i,"a_id"]==data_test[,"a_id"] &
                     identifiers_test[i,"condition"]==data_test[,"condition"] &
                     identifiers_test[i,"time_of_change"]==data_test[,"time_of_change"]),]

  # Sort data by highest prediction
  data_test_offer = data_test_offer[order(-data_test_offer[,"prediction"]),]

  if(data_test_offer[1,"is_v"]==1){
    true_counter <- true_counter+1
  }
}
```

How can i refactor this, to make it more "R" - and faster?

Comment: Take a look at `by` or `split` in base.

Comment: Depending on what you want to do with the data, you might not even need to split it into several smaller data.frames (or a list of data.frames) - packages like `dplyr` or `data.table` allow very efficient data manipulation by group(s). Check them out if you don't already know them.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, that sounds like good advise. I will take a look at them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before applying groups you are filtering your data.frame using another data.frame. I would use `merge` then `by`.

```
ID <- c("m_id","a_id","condition","time_of_change")
filter_data <- merge(data_test,identifiers_test,by=ID)
by(filter_data,   do.call(paste,filter_data[,ID]),
      FUN=function(x)x[order(-x[,"prediction"]),])
```

Of course the same thing can be written using `data.table` more efficiently:

```
library(data.table)
setkeyv(setDT(identifiers_test),ID)
setkeyv(setDT(data_test),ID)
data_test[identifiers_test][rev(order(prediction)),,ID]
```

NOTE: the answer below is not tested since you don't provide a data to test it.

Comment: data.table is huge. Thank you very much.